# Birthdate validation issues

Tags: php, validation, date

I have some PHP validation code written to validate a date of birth. The code is supposed to make sure that a entry is made, (mandatory field) the format is `DD/MM/YYYY` and the year must be between 2000 & 2004.

The problem I am having with my code is that it properly checks if an entry is not made and relays the error message but if I enter any random characters it accepts it without checking the format or characters of the entered data.

Here is my code :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$msgd = "";
$dob = $_POST["dob"];

if(strlen($dob) > 0) {
    if(substr_count($dob,'/') == 2)
    {
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/',$dob);
        if (($y >= 2000 && $y <= 2004))
        {
        return checkdate($d,$m,$y);
        } else {
        $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
        }
    }
    } else {
    $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a date</b></span>';
}
}

?>

<b>Date of Birth</b>
<br>
<input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"><?php echo $msgd; ?>
```

Could anyone help me with a solution for this?

Comment: I see `return` here, but no function header. And I wonder what's shown to user if `$_POST['submit']` is not set.

Comment: Or you could save your self a lot of trouble and make the month, day, year dropdown menus. This way you know the values will be valid no matter what, and you only have to validate if blank or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would just look at using a regular expression to validate the date

```
$pattern = '#^((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))/((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/(200[0-4])$#';

if (1 === preg_match($pattern, $dob) {
   // date is valid
} else {
   // date is invalid
}
```

You can even capture the sub-pattern for month, day, and year if you like.

```
$1 => day sub-pattern
$4 => month sub-pattern
$8 => year sub-pattern
```

Or use named subpattern like this:

```
$pattern = '#^(?<day>(0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))/(?<month>(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/(?<year>200[0-4])$#';
if (1 === preg_match($pattern, $dob, $matches)) {
    // date is valid
    $day = $matches['day'];
    $month = $matches['month'];
    $year = $matches['year'];
} else {
    // date is invalid
}
```

The benefit of using this regex is that it avoids having to write a bunch of lines of code to explode the date and then validate each individual day/month/year component individually.

Comment: ah great the second set of code worked just fine, thanks so much!

Comment: @francis Please note an edit.  It seems one of my edit to change order of day/month did not take originally (I had them in wrong order order at first).  This most recent update has them in correct order.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$msgd = "";
$dob = $_POST["dob"];

if(strlen($dob) > 0) {
    if(substr_count($dob,'/') == 2)
    {
        list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/',$dob);
        if (($y >= 2000 && $y <= 2004))
        {
        ?>
          <b>Date of Birth</b>
          <br>
          <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"><?php echo $msgd; 
       } else {
        $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
        }
    }
    } else {
    $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a date</b></span>';
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
if (($y >= 2000 && $y <= 2004))
{
    return checkdate($d,$m,$y);
} else {
    $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
}
```

to:

```
if (($y >= 2000 && $y <= 2004) && checkdate($m, $d, $y))
{
    $msgd = 'The date is fine!';
} else {
    $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
}
```

The values you provided to `checkdate()` are in the wrong order. Also, i've moved the `checkdate()` function to the `if` condition.

You don't need to use the `return` keyword either, because this code doesn't look to be in a function.

**EDIT**

Try this code:

```
<?php
    $msgd = '';
    $dob = '';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $dob = $_POST["dob"];

        if(strlen($dob) > 0) {
            if(substr_count($dob,'/') == 2)
            {
                list($d,$m,$y) = explode('/',$dob);

                if(!is_numeric($d) || !is_numeric($m) || !is_numeric($y))
                { 
                    $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
                } else {

                    if (($y >= 2000 && $y <= 2004) && checkdate($m, $d, $y))
                    {
                        $msgd = 'The date is fine!';
                    } else {
                        $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a correct date</b></span>';
            }
        } else {
            $msgd = '<span class="error"><b>You must enter a date</b></span>';
        }
    }
?>

<b>Date of Birth</b>
<br>
<input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" value="<?php echo $dob; ?>"><?php echo $msgd; ?>
```

Comment: tried this out just now as well, same problem, it takes whatever i enter and doesn't even display the text 'The date is fine!' for reason either.

Comment: Can you give us an example date the user is entering?

Comment: Also, just before the `if` condition, what is outputted when you do a `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: If you mean correct date format than it would something like 15/02/2001.
The data i am purposely incorrectly entering to make sure that it gives me the error "you must enter a correct date" is just random alphabetical characters.

Comment: I've made an edit, I've taken all your code and rewritten it to how it should hopefully work. If you want to give that a try, and if it doesn't work, comment :)